# How to print "public" IP address of website you are on?

Tags: php, ip, host

So far I have tried:

`echo gethostbyname(gethostname());`

But this give me the "local" IP (not sure if that's the right term) `127.0.0.1`, whereas I want the "public" IP address.

Eg, for the website stackoverflow.com I get `151.101.193.69` when using the website service https://ipinfo.info ... that is what I am looking for.

Comment: You have to connect to another server to determine its IP address, unless it is hardcoded somewhere in the configuration.

Comment: If you tried to get the public IP of my company's website, you'd get different answers depending on time of day, country and a bunch of other things, because we're behind Cloudflare. But generally speaking, you could lookup the A or CNAME record of the site, that might get you a little bit what you are looking for. But I'd query a public DNS server, too, not an internal one.

Comment: Hm I see, so it would be best then to perhaps call a third party API and print the output from that? Eg https://ipapi.com

Comment: I guess it really depends on what you are doing. For one of my clients, when I VPN into their network, the IP of their server changes from a public one into a private 10.x.x.x address. That's an edge case however.

Comment: It's actually so I can monitor if it changes vs what I have recorded. =)

Comment: In that case, either use an API, or use a DNS lookup. For the latter, I haven't tried it, but according to the comments in the docs, if you append a period to the domain name it will use the machine's DNS instead of a possible host file. `gethostbyname(gethostname() . '.')` I've never tried this but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
function getIPAddress() {  
 //whether ip is from the share internet
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {  
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];  
    }  
 //whether ip is from the proxy 
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {  
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];  
 }  
//whether ip is from the remote address 
else{  
         $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
 }  
 return $ip;
```

}